# Query into Table View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I use Parse for my backend data. Here, I saved an array of dictionaries to then query into my app and load into my tableview.

Here is my array saved in Parse:

[image]

When I query it in the `viewDidLoad` I set my empty array (self.dealListArray) equal to the array on Parse.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The first `NSLog()` outputs the entire array from Parse perfectly. But the second NSLog outside of the brackets output NULL.

The table view will not load up because my array is NULL. How can I keep the information from the query so that I can fill it with my table view?

Thank you, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Because it's async. [yourTableView reloadData] after the `self.dealListArray = [resMenu objectForKey:@"Deals"];` possibly calling it in mainQueue (since it's related to UI).

Comment: You can build out the querying and updating mechanisms yourself or you can use the Parse provided `PFQueryTableViewController` in the ParseUI framework. It automatically takes care of showing an activity indicator, refreshing the table with the fetched data when complete, pagination, and tons of other convenience methods

Answer (score 2):

You have no real guarantee when the block is called. So it's probably best that you wait until the data is loaded and meanwhile to have a [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/index.html) or something similar to indicate that something is being loaded.

Also, when the block does get called and you change the value of dealListArray you would have to reload the tableview's data.

like this...

```
self.dealListArray = [resMenu objectForKey@"Deals"];
NSLog(@"%@", self.dealListArray];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```